# Не обнаружен уникальный индекс для адресуемого поля

Tags: ms-access

Мне из таблицы АвтоВодитель нужны соединить autoID c полем Автомобиль из таблицы Заказы, так же сделать с водителем, но выходит ошибка: "Не обнаружен уникальный индекс для адресуемого поля".
Нужно соединить именно из таблицы АвтоВодитель, а не из Автомобиль и Водитель, потому что у по логике у нас есть запрещенные автомобили для некоторых водителей(например водитель не может водить грузовики). Чтобы не получилось так что мы водителю можем приписать грузовик, а пользоваться он им не может.
Как исправить ошибку?

Вот моя схема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неверная структура у таблицы АвтоВодитель - естественный ключ тут не подходит, ибо данная связь является самостоятельной сущностью (неправильно выполнен анализ предметной области). Должно быть ключевое автоинкрементное поле (его использовать для ссылки) и два поля-внешние ссылки.

Comment: То есть у меня должен быть обычный ID, и autiID и driverID, но они уже не будут являться ключевыми полями?

Comment: Да. Ну и вообще - забудьте про естественные ключи, они оправданы крайне редко. Используйте везде синтетику.

Comment: Все равно тип соединения неопределенно, почему? Выглядит таблица АвтоВодитель так ID(PK), autoID, driverID, как мне соединить autoID и driverID c полями водитель и автомобиль?

Comment: *как мне соединить autoID и driverID c полями водитель и автомобиль?* В таблице Заказы должно быть одно поле АвтоВодитель_ID, а не два отдельных поля. Его и связывать.